# Geoserver: sortBy for property named as number leads to ClassCastException

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I have an SQL view layer in Geoserver, with almost all properties named as integer numbers (e.g. 76096294). When I request Geoserver's WFS to sort features by such property, it returns

> {
>       "version": "2.0.0",
>       "exceptions": [
>           {
>               "code": "NoApplicableCode",
>               "locator": "noLocator",
>               "text": "java.lang.ClassCastException"
>           }
>       ]}

My full request string looks like this

```
http://hostname/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=workspace:layer_name&outputFormat=application/json&exceptions=application/json&srsName=EPSG:3857&startIndex=0&count=20&sortBy=76096294&viewparams=register_id:76098281
```

But sortBy with property named as string (e.g. feature_id) works just as expected.
In geoserver logs I see just

> 2018-11-09 15:52:59,381 ERROR [org.geoserver.ows] -
>   java.lang.ClassCastException

Does anyone know any solution/have any suggestion how to do sort by property named as integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoServer (and WFS in general) expect that a dataset can be exported as GML (an XML extension) for this reason a valid attribute name must be a [valid XML element name](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html) so it is illegal for it to start with a number.

So at some point in its travels through GeoServer your request is found to be invalid as it can't be asking for just a number as that would be an illegal XML name. The easiest answer is to change the name of your attribute.